# React Native com NavigationActions Redux Saga e Reactotron

Tags: react-native

Boa tarde, estava tentando fazer uma navegação dentro de uma action do redux com o seguinte código:

```
 export function* searchByID(action) {
  try {
    console.log('action', action);
    const response = yield call(apiGetProdutoByID, action.idProduto);

    console.log('produto', response);

    yield put({
      type: TypesProdutos.SEARCH_BY_ID,
      produto: response.data.data.obj,
    });

    const produto = yield select(state => state.produtos);
    console.log(produto);

    **yield put(
      NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName: action.route,
        params: {produto: produto},
      }),**
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    yield put({type: TypesProdutos.FAIL});
  }
}
```

Porém a linha em negrito, não funciona, então fui aconselhada a utilizar debugue com o reactotron porém ao tentar integrar ele ao meu projeto com os seguintes códigos:

Arquivo ReactotronConfig.js

```
import Reactotron from 'reactotron-react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import {reactotronRedux as reduxPlugin} from 'reactotron-redux';
import sagaPlugin from 'reactotron-redux-saga';

const reactotron = Reactotron;

Reactotron.setAsyncStorageHandler(AsyncStorage) // AsyncStorage would either come from `react-native` or `@react-native-community/async-storage` depending on where you get it from
  .configure() // controls connection & communication settings
  .useReactNative() // add all built-in react native plugins
  .use(reduxPlugin())
  .use(sagaPlugin())
  .connect(); // let's connect!

export default reactotron;
```

index.js

```
if (__DEV__) {
  import('./ReactotronConfig').then(() => console.log('Reactotron Configured'));
}
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './src';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

index.js onde exporto o store

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import rootReducer from './ducks';
import rootSaga from './sagas';
import Reactotron from 'reactotron-react-native';

const sagaMonitor = Reactotron.createSagaMonitor;
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware({sagaMonitor});

const middleware = applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware);

const store = createStore(rootReducer, middleware);

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export default store;
```

Porém aparece o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Após dar um npm install e alterar o arquivo que exporta o store o app voltou a rodar.

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import rootReducer from './ducks';
import rootSaga from './sagas';
import Reactotron from 'reactotron-react-native';
import ReactotronConfig from '../../ReactotronConfig';

const sagaMonitor = Reactotron.createSagaMonitor;
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware({sagaMonitor});

const middleware = applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware);

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(
    middleware,
    ReactotronConfig.createEnhancer(),
  ),
);

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export default store;
```